# How to use Document#update in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm looking at the example here for Document#update in Mongoose:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-update

**Method signature:**

> Document#update(doc, options, callback)

**Example code:**

> weirdCar.update({$inc: {wheels:1}}, { w: 1 }, callback);

The documentation says the first parameter should be "doc" but what exactly is doc? I would imagine doc should just be an object that maps keys to new values to be updated (by default $set is used). In the code example they are trying to increment wheels by 1.

Then in the example they pass {w : 1} as options but "w" is not a valid option according to Model.Update. The only valid options should be: safe, upsert, multi, strict.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update

Can someone explain the example code provided by Mongoose?

Answer (score 4):

The key for me was the correct parameters. You need to supply the `callback` parameter or call `.exec()` on the result for it to work.

```
var Product = mongoose.model('product', mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
}));
Product.findById('539dceccc61fa4950b43423a', function (err, product) {
    product.update({ name: 'test' }, null, function(err, numberAffected, raw) { });
    //or
    product.update({ name: 'test' }).exec();
});
```

Comment: that was really helpful. wasted so much time just cause I forgot the exec part.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me like the docs are wrong.

Further, some people don't understand the issue here.  We're trying to call `update` on a DOCUMENT.  NOT query for the document while performing an update.  There's a difference, and it's not very well documented by Mongoose.

Here's what the documentation says:  about `document.update`

*example:* `weirdCar.update({$inc: {wheels:1}}, { w: 1 }, callback);`

**Parameters:**

```
doc <Object>
options <Object>
callback <Function>
```

**Valid Options**

```
same as in Model.update
```

*so lets have a look at Model.updates options*...

**Model.updates options:**

- safe (boolean) safe mode (defaults to value set in schema (true))
- upsert (boolean) whether to create the doc if it doesn't match (false)
- multi (boolean) whether multiple documents should be updated (false)
- runValidators: if true, runs update validators on this command. Update validators validate the update operation against the model's schema.
- setDefaultsOnInsert: if this and upsert are true, mongoose will apply the defaults specified in the model's schema if a new document is created. This option only works on MongoDB >= 2.4 because it relies on MongoDB's $setOnInsert operator.
- strict (boolean) overrides the strict option for this update
- overwrite (boolean) disables update-only mode, allowing you to overwrite the doc (false)

There's nothing there that corresponds with that example... There is no mention of `{w : 1}` or `w` anything...  So yes, it appears that the docs are wrong.

However, you can use it with or without those options.

**So it looks like this without any options**

```
weirdCar.update({$inc: {wheels:1}}, function(err, updated) {
      // 'updated' is the object: {ok: number, nModified: number, n: number}
})
```

Comment: Is there any way via which we can get the updated document in the callback? I want to push a new object in the document and want that same to be returned in the callback

Answer (score 1):

The Mongoose api is based on the underlying MongoDB query structure.  In this case, "doc" refers to a criteria for matching certain documents that you want to update.  The MongoDB docs explain this very clearly: 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-operations/#update

So, let's say that you had a 'cars' collection, and you wanted to find all documents (all cars) that had 3 wheels, and increment that value so those cars had 4 wheels.  In this case, "doc" is { wheels : 3 }, which returns all three-wheeled cars in the collection.  Here is the basic query in the MongoDB shell:

```
> db.cars.update( { wheels : 3 }, { $inc : { wheels : 1 } } );
```

In Mongoose, you can add additional parameters for options and a callback function, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: i think this corresponds to http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update rather than http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-update